# ISNULL() On Value, But If Not Null, Put Quotes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am building dynamic SQL statements. I am checking for null values, and if the value is not null, putting single quotes around the parameter value. In the below `@TEST_GU` is a string parameter.

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = 'UPDATE [THIS IS A TABLE]
SET [TEST_GU]=' + '''' + ISNULL(@TEST_GU,'') + ''''+', 
+ ' SELECT [TEST_GU] FROM 
[THIS IS A TABLE]
WHERE [TEST_GU] =' + '''' + ISNULL(@TEST_GU,'') + '''' +''
PRINT LEN(@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)
COMMIT
```

This wont work because if its null, it ends up putting quotes around the empty value, so makes the whole statement become unformatted. So my question is, in the above format, is it possible to check for null values, if null use the second argument of the `ISNULL` method (in this case, an empty ''). If it is not null, put the parameter value in single quotes.

Comment: I don't think the quote quite all match up correctly in given code. Plus you can combine some stuff to reduce the concatenations. 'UPDATE [THIS IS A TABLE]
SET [TEST_GU]=' + '''' is probably better as 'UPDATE [THIS IS A TABLE]
SET [TEST_GU]='''. Whereas + '''' +'' doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the quotes *inside* the `isnull()`:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'UPDATE [THIS IS A TABLE]
SET [TEST_GU]=' + '''' + ISNULL(''''+@TEST_GU+'''','') + ''''+', 
+ ' SELECT [TEST_GU] FROM 
[THIS IS A TABLE]
```

The concatenation will return `NULL` if the value is `NULL`, so it still does what you want.